# Why string parameter shares the same address with the argument

Tags: c++, string, parameters, copy, arguments

I wrote a function using a string object as the parameter:

```
void func(string str)
```

When I use GDB to debug it in Linux, I found that `str` has the same value of `_M_p` as the corresponding argument passed(`test_string`).

Does it mean that `str` and `test_string` share the same string data?
What's the reason for that?
Does it have something to do with the bit copy process by the copy constructor?

Comment: More info please. give an example. Are you modifying the string withing func? what compiler options do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC's implementation of C++ string uses a copy-on-write strategy for performance concerns.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write

```
std::string x("Hello");
std::string y = x;  // x and y use the same buffer
y += ", World!";    // now y uses a different buffer
                    // x still uses the same old buffer
```

Comment: Not "C++ string" in general, but GCC's implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

GCC had -- I'm not sure it is still the case but backward compatibility would ask for it -- a copy on write (COW) implementation of std::string.  That means that copying of dynamically allocated resources occurs only when necessary.

It has no relationship with the default implementation of copy constructors, a COW implementation of std::string needs a copy constructor which does something (note that the representation is shared and thus need to be copied if modifications occurs).

Answer (score 1):

Library writers can implement `std::string` with some form of [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) optimization: when you copy a string (as is happening in your example), the two copies share the string data. An actual copy of the data (which can be expensive) will only happen if one of the two strings are actually modified.

This will in general be more efficient than copying the whole data each time a copy is made. (But care has to be taken for thread-safety in particular.)

You could find this article interesting: [C++ String Performance](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-string-performance/184405453), it mentions this type of implementation.